# Вывод числа до 2-х знаков до запятой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть числа, к примеру: `1 230 000`,  `22 345 500`, `333 456 000`, ...

Есть ли возможность в js окргулить эти числа и вывести в виде `1`, `22`, `333`, ... соответственно, т.е. отбрасывая последние 6 знаков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое решение помогло:

```js
$('.num').each(function(){
  var num = $(this).text().split("").slice(0, -6).join("");
            $(this).html(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
  <div class="num">1234000</div>
  <div class="num">22345000</div>
  <div class="num">333456000</div>
```

Comment: А почему мой ответ не подходит?

Comment: @YernarSadybekov, а Вы пробовали его реализовать? Ничего что там все так же и останется только после запятой?!

Comment: Извините, я уже исправил ответ. И думаю что мой ответ более подходящий.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.num').each(function(){
  var num = Math.floor(parseInt($(this).text())/1000000);
  $(this).html(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="num">1234000</div>
<div class="num">22345000</div>
<div class="num">333456000</div>
```